# problem with .htaccess configuration in cakephp3

Tags: .htaccess, server, configuration, localhost, cakephp-3.0

i have a problem since one week about my cakephp3 project. i have developped a cakephp3 project in localhost and it works very fine. in my server i have created a subdomain and i have uploaded my project on it. when i execute my project, i have this error message

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster@collector.oiecameroun.org to inform them of the time this
>   error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

i think the problem is in the .htaccess file root but i don't know what is the problem. i need help please. my php version is 7.2
this is my .htaccess file root content:

```
# Uncomment the following to prevent the httpoxy vulnerability
# See: https://httpoxy.org/
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    RequestHeader unset Proxy
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So, what did the server error log file reveal which you are pointed to in that message?

Answer (score 0):

this is the error log file content

> [03-Oct-2019 07:43:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  You must enable the intl
>   extension to use CakePHP.  in
>   /home/cp1035698p49/public_html/collector/config/requirements.php on
>   line 31

and this problem was also resolved